# How Google Cloud Messaging Service in Android Works?

Tags: android, android-c2dm, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use GCM Service in my application.

I have referred to the following link ([Android Developer: Google GCM](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)) but was not able to install the GCM Library in my eclipse.

From the SDK manager I am not getting GCM Library in the Extras Folder.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had similar issues and it was resolved once I updated Android SDK Tools to revision 20 and Android Platform SDK Tools to revision 12. Rev 19/11 would not shown up **Extras > Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library** in *SDK Manager*.  And make sure that you restart SDK manager after updating.

It should then show up in SDK manager as shown bellow:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I had to check for updates on eclipse to update the SDK manager. Works now.

Comment: I updated to revision 20 and everything work just fine, but I feel that new platform tools in slower than previous version. My avds run slower... Idk why ?

Answer (score 1):

For me just an update don't work. But try to download and install new Android SDK from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. After installing this it finally shows me new libraries in extras.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help->Check for updates, and update your eclipse. After update you will get "Google Cloud Messaging for Android library" in Extras

Answer (score 1):

Or use in **path-to-android-sdk/tools/**

```
./android.bat update sdk
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem i solved it by:
First Close SDK Manager.
Then open AVD Manager click on "Tools" > "Options" And then click on "Clear cache"
then close AVD Manager,And open SDK Manager and click "Packages" > "Reload"
And there is it API 16(Android 4.1 JB) 
And At Extras "Google Cloud Messaging for Android libary"

Answer (score 1):

0pen Android Skd manager,Go to Extra and Install the Google Clouds messaging for android.
After installation,open the Android SKD->Extra->google and import the gcm project to your IDE
Now you have gcm.jar in libs folder.