# ADT Plugin disappeared in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, sdk, adt

..I was trying to install the Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library, from the Extra in Android SDK Manager.

Since it did not appear, I updateded the Android SDK Tools and the Android SDK Platform-Tools to the last release (as shown here: [How Google Cloud Messaging Service in Android Works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241756/how-google-cloud-messaging-service-in-android-works)).

Once updated both, I still could not find any Extras--> Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library (just "Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager"). So I updated Eclipse (version 3.6) too (Help->Check for Updates), but nothing happened except for the fact that **the ADT plugin was not there anymore**: no Android menu under Preferences, no possibilty to create Android projects and so on.

I uninstelled the plugin, removed the files from the plugin directory, installed another version of Eclipse (3.8) with the addition of the plugin but **nothing changed**.

Any ideas?

I'm working on a Mac OS X Leopard.

Comment: If your question is solved, you should post an answer and accept it instead of putting *solved* into your title

Comment: Can you post a link to the source that helped you determine that 64-bit Java is required for ADT 20? That statement is misleading since I am running Eclipse 3.7.2 + ADT 20.0.2 on a 32-bit Fedora Core 16 Linux box.

Comment: Probably you are right, it just requires the Java 1.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the new ADT Plugin (v20) requires Java 1.6.

So, first of all, I had to change the Java Preferences, bringing up the 1.6 Java version.

Then, since my Eclipse was set for Java 1.5 32 bit, I had to download the 64 bit Eclipse release (because my 1.6 Java version was 64 bit).

And everything worked again.

Hope this can help.

Comment: In my case the "-vm" option of Eclipse had been removed for any reason and the PATH with JAVA_HOME was corrupted for any reason (I had to move the JAVA_HOME to the beginning of the PATH). Setting back the "-vm" eclipse option with a 1.6 JDK solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Beginning with ADT 17 "Java 1.6 or higher is required for ADT 17.0.0."
http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html